# Error manenando Hilos en Python RuntimeError: can'r start new thread

Tags: hilos

Lo que hace mi programa es que constantemente esta recibiendo información de manera serial, por lo que la estoy imprimiendo en la consola. Todo esto mientras espera que se teclee una tecla y que reciba información mediante teclado. En si el proyecto esta conectado a Arduino a una Raspberry, y la información serial que recibe es la que manda el Arduino.
Ya logre realizar lo que quería, mas sin embargo a los pocos minutos ya sea que este manipulando el programa o lo deje andar llega un punto donde sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
import serial
import threading
import time

arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS1',baudrate=9600,timeout=1.0)

def waitingForWrite(caracter):
    try:
        valorDeEntrada = input()
        print(valorDeEntrada)
        writeX = arduino.write(valorDeEntrada.encode())
        time.sleep(5)
    except ValueError:
        print()
    
while True:
    line = arduino.readline()
    if(line.decode()!=''):
        print(line.decode('utf-8'))
    hilo = threading.Thread(target=waitingForWrite,args=("Waiting",))
    hilo.start()
```

Comment: Creo que te falta código relevante, no veo cuando defines la clase `hilo`, ni el método `start`, el fallo se da en dicho método y no lo adjuntaste. ://